# how to change a object value in VUE.js

Tags: object, vue.js

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      a: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    //a function that can get data from backend
    getdata() {
      someAPI.getdata.then(response => {
        // manage this data
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if ((data[i]["name"] = "Peter")) {
            this.a["peter"] = [
              { age: data[i]["age"], grade: "9" },
              { age: data[i]["age"], grade: "9" }
            ];
          } else if ((data[i]["name"] = "Wong")) {
            this.a["peter"] = [
              { age: data[i]["age"], grade: "9" },
              { age: data[i]["age"], grade: "9" }
            ];
          }
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getdata();
  }
};
```

this function I changed the a object in data.but in another function I want to console.log to watch. if I `console.log(this.a)` I can get whole object

```
{'Peter':[
{'age': 11, 'grade': '9'},{'age': 12, 'grade': '9'},
],'Wong':[{'age': 13, 'grade': '9'}, {'age': 14, 'grade': '9'},]}
```

But if I `console.log(this.a['Peter'])` or `console.log(this.a.Peter)` than I will get a null object, but why?
I have use `this.$set` but it does not work.

Comment: use `this.$set(this.a, 'peter', [...])` instead of `this.a['peter'] = ...`

Comment: I see in `getdata` you assigned object to `this.a['peter']` but in the end of question you try to access via `this.a['Peter']. Is it just typo? because keys in js object are case-sensetive.

Comment: I used this.$set but not work.

Comment: Your example is disordered. Organizing it, I noticed what the problem might be. You do not have access to `data` (and `this` was also missing). This function creates *Vue* data for you that you will refer to `this.a`

Comment: I mean, you have a construction like `if ((data[i]["name"] = "Peter")) {}` which is not a test expression but an assignment expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
this.$set(this.student,"age", 24)
```

like this